# Facebook APP Multiple Domains

Tags: ruby, facebook, ruby-on-rails-3.1, devise, omniauth

I am setting up a Ruby on Rails app to allow login via Facebook with Devise + Omniauth.  I can got this working no problem with the APP ID and Token.

However I am having an issue that I am not sure how to get around.

I have 1 instance of the Rails app running on `Server A` I have 2 domain names `www.domain-one.com` and `www.domain-two.com` which point to `Server A` When I create the app in Facebook for `www.domain-one.com` it works ok but as soon as I add `www.domain-two.com` to the app domains it gives me and error "domain must be derived from your Site URL".  Is it possible to allow multiple domains login with the same Facebook APP IDs?

If not then would an acceptable solution be to switch the details in the devise initializer file based on domain and does anyone know how to get the domain from an devise initializer?

Hope you understand what I mean.

Tony

Answer (score 0):

You can specify multiple subdomains but they can only belong to one domain. That's because it must match the URL in the Website with Facebook Login > Site URL.

In this case, you can make one domain name as primary domain pointing to server A and the other one as secondary domain redirecting to first domain. then In facebook app use the second domain as site url.

There is another benefit of following this strategy, your websites SEO will be improved. if search engines find one content from different domains then it rank down the content, unique content from unique address increases the ranking.